# Capture audio with AMR-NB encoding in UWP?

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, codec, amr

On the [supported codecs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/supported-codecs) page, AMR-NB is listed as one of the few encodings that is supported for both encode and decode on a variety of platforms.  However, it is conspicuously absent from any of the `AudioEncodingProperties` "Create" methods, such as `AudioEncodingProperties.CreateMp3` but no corresponding `AudioEncodingProperties.CreateAmr` method.  All attempts to create an AMR encoder by hand have failed with the classic ambiguous UWP HRESULT-based exception.

For example,

```cs
var capture = new MediaCapture();

await capture.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
{
    MediaCategory = MediaCategory.Speech,
        StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio
});

var recordProfile = new MediaEncodingProfile
{
    Audio = new AudioEncodingProperties
    {
        BitsPerSample = 16,
        ChannelCount = 1,
        SampleRate = 8000,
        Subtype = "AMRNB"
    }
};

ContainerEncodingProperties containerProperties = new ContainerEncodingProperties
{
    Subtype = "AMR" // tried this with every known container
};

recordProfile.Container = containerProperties;
recordProfile.Video = null;

var file = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.CreateFileAsync("captured.amr",
    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await capture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(recordProfile, file); // this throws
```

results in `System.Exception: 'The requested attribute was not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D36E6)'`

Answer (score 1):

Had to add this line to set the "auto preset mode":

```cs
recordProfile.Audio.Properties.Add(new Guid("23e5cad8-a3fc-4f0f-97c3-dff51d03bc92"), 1.ToString());
```